# Print milliseconds only (0 to 999)

Tags: java, date, time

I have worked a bit on the following code but still unable to print milliseconds (not all the millisecond from epoch time to user defined time).
Where am I lacking to print remaining milliseconds e.g. If seconds are 30 exactly, milliseconds should be only 0. Milliseconds should not be more than 999 obviously.

```
    // Sets current date by default
    Calendar ob = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Sets user defined date with year, month, day of month respectively
    Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
    dob.set(1990, 3, 25);

    // Want to get milliseconds only (0 - 999)
    long milli = dob.getTimeInMillis() - ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12 * ( ob.get(Calendar.YEAR) - dob.get(Calendar.YEAR) ) );
    System.out.println(milli);
```

Comment: Is it Java? Add the language tag.

Comment: java? if can better put java tag.

Comment: Surely you just need to do long milli = (ob.getTimeInMillis() - dob.getTimeInMillis()) % 1000;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do

```
long justMillis = dob.getTimeInMillis() % 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want what's called the modulus operator, `%`. This basically finds the remainder of division.

```
long milli = dob.getTimeInMillis() % 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(milli % 1000);
```